# Laravel 5: Set Input parameters to another function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following function in my Controller class:

```
public function functionA(){
   $name=Input::get('name');
   $age=Input::get('age');
   ...
   //the rest of the function
   ...
}
```

It works fine...

Now, I have another function in which the parameters are passed as JSON:

```
public function functionB(){
    $params = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $name = isset($params->name) ? trim($params->name) : "";
    $age = isset($params->age) ? trim($params->age) : "";

    //I want to do this to save having to write functionA twice:
    Input::set('xxx'... ??? Can I do this?
    $this->functionA();
}
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Input::get()` you should use `Request()` in laravel 5. You can inject this into your method:

```
public function functionA(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
   $name=$request->name;
   $age=$request->age;

   ...
   //the rest of the function
   ...
}
```

After that, your question gets quite vague, but I'm guessing you are calling function B from within function A. So you could simply pass the `$request` object over there:

```
public function functionB(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
    $params = $request; // Not needed, you can simply use $request below...
    $name = isset($params->name) ? trim($params->name) : "";
    $age = isset($params->age) ? trim($params->age) : "";

    //I want to do this to save having to write functionA twice:
    $request->xxx = 'whatever you want';
    $this->functionA($request);
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your message. But I want to continue calling functionB directly using POST parameters. If I pass a $request parameter, will that interfere?

Comment: All the post parameters are in $request if you inject that facade to your controller, so yes, you can do this! @Eamorr. You can allways access them as shown in my answers functionA!

Comment: I think this is the solution. You have been incredibly helpful and saved me a huge amount of time. I need to remove all the `Input::` bits from my code... Thank you!

Comment: Once you have done this, working with `Request` is very convenient. @Eamorr